# How to number SQL results sequentially?

Tags: mysql

Given following query -

```
SELECT name, age FROM students WHERE age > 22
```

The result is -

```
name    age
----   ---
Kshitiz 23
Steve   22
Paul    24
```

How can I number the results sequentially? Like so -

```
serial  name    age
------  ----    ---
   1    Kshitiz 23
   2    Steve   22
   3    Paul    24
```

Please note that using surrogate key is not a solution. Because the surrogate id for record Kshitiz might be 9. I want whatever results are returned from whatever location to be numbered sequentially.

Comment: ordered by `name`?

Comment: @ypercube Yup that would do.

Comment: See this similar question: **[Sorting the Table and getting the position](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18316/sorting-the-table-and-getting-the-position)**. You only need the `ROW_NUMBER` "function".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT @a := @a + 1 serial, name, age
FROM students, (SELECT @a :=0) AS dummy
WHERE age > 22;
```

This works for MySQL. I was modifying from [this example](http://theoryapp.com/generate-serial-number-in-sql/).

Comment: You should have an `ORDER BY something`, otherwise it's a more or less random ordering.